# How to display data errors on load with bootstrap-table and x-editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I am trying to populate a bootstrap-table with several editable fields using the editable (x-editable) extension. The fields are pulled in from a url. On the server side we run some validation checks and pass back an array of which fields contained errors.

How can I display those errors on page load with the editable plug in? 
So that the second the page loads, the user can identify which data is incorrect.

[See example: JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebellefontaine/9p62op19/)

**HTML**

```
<table id="table">

</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
var data = [
    {
        "name": "bootstrap-table",
        "stargazers_count": "526",
        "forks_count": "122",
        "description": "An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3) ",
        "errors": "{'name','stargazers_count','forks_count'}"
    },
    {
        "name": "multiple-select",
        "stargazers_count": "288",
        "forks_count": "150",
        "description": "A jQuery plugin to select multiple elements with checkboxes :)",
        "errors": "{}"
    },
    {
        "name": "bootstrap-show-password",
        "stargazers_count": "32",
        "forks_count": "11",
        "description": "Show/hide password plugin for twitter bootstrap.",
        "errors": "{'forks_count'}"
    },
    {
        "name": "blog",
        "stargazers_count": "13",
        "forks_count": "4",
        "description": "my blog",
        "errors": "{'stargazers_count', 'name'}"
    },
    {
        "name": "scutech-redmine",
        "stargazers_count": "6",
        "forks_count": "3",
        "description": "Redmine notification tools for chrome extension.",
        "errors": "{}"
    }
];

$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
            columns: [
            {
            field: 'name',
          title: 'Name',
          editable: {
            type: 'text'
          }
          },{
          field: 'stargazers_count',
          title: 'Stars',
          editable: {
            type: 'text'
          }
          },{
            field: 'forks_count',
            title: 'Forks',
            editable: {
                type: 'text'
            }
          },{
          field: 'errors',
          title: 'Errors',
          }
        ],
        data: data
    });
});
```

To give you another example of what I am trying to do. Lets say that the value 'newName' got saved to the 'name' field in our database. When we go to our page with the bootstrap table displaying all the names of users, the one with the value 'newName' would be highlighted red, and an error message would say something like "Error: newName is not valid, please change".

I know someone is going to ask why we aren't validating the data on save. In this case users are allowed to enter bad data that normally wouldn't pass validation checks (consider it draft data), this is done from a different webpage. Then at a later time, say next login, they decide they are done with the draft data and ready to submit it. The user would click a submit button, and be brought to this page being asked to review and correct their data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrap table does provide the formatter option but that does not seem to work with the editable extension (review https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/develop/src/extensions/editable/bootstrap-table-editable.js#L65 for more detail).

It's still possible, first set the formatter for the columns and then on post body event the script can update the table. Search for 'cfa' to review additions in the snippet.

```js
/* begin cfa */
function errorFormatter(value, row, index) {
  var thisCellValue = value;
  var thisRowData = row;
  var thisRowErrorsString = thisRowData.errors;

  for (var aKey in thisRowData) {
    if (thisRowData[aKey] == thisCellValue) {
      if (thisRowErrorsString.indexOf(aKey) != -1) {
        return value + ' has_errors';
      }
    }
  }

  return thisCellValue;
};
/* end cfa */

var data = [{
  "name": "bootstrap-table",
  "stargazers_count": "526",
  "forks_count": "122",
  "description": "An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3) ",
  "errors": "{'name','stargazers_count','forks_count'}"
}, {
  "name": "multiple-select",
  "stargazers_count": "288",
  "forks_count": "150",
  "description": "A jQuery plugin to select multiple elements with checkboxes :)",
  "errors": "{}"
}, {
  "name": "bootstrap-show-password",
  "stargazers_count": "32",
  "forks_count": "11",
  "description": "Show/hide password plugin for twitter bootstrap.",
  "errors": "{'forks_count'}"
}, {
  "name": "blog",
  "stargazers_count": "13",
  "forks_count": "4",
  "description": "my blog",
  "errors": "{'stargazers_count', 'name'}"
}, {
  "name": "scutech-redmine",
  "stargazers_count": "6",
  "forks_count": "3",
  "description": "Redmine notification tools for chrome extension.",
  "errors": "{}"
}];

$(function() {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    /* begin cfa */
    onPostBody: function() {
      $('[data-value!=""]').each(function(each_element) {
        var thisElement = this;
        var thisElementDataValue = $(thisElement).data('value') + " ";

        if (thisElementDataValue != null && thisElementDataValue.indexOf("has_errors") != -1) {
          $(thisElement).data('value', thisElementDataValue.substring(0, thisElementDataValue.indexOf("has_errors")));
          $(thisElement).text(thisElementDataValue.replace('has_errors', 'is invalid'));
          $(thisElement).css("color", "red");
        }
      });
    },
    /* end cfa */
    columns: [{
      field: 'name',
      title: 'Name',
      editable: {
        type: 'text'
      },
      formatter: errorFormatter, /* cfa */
    }, {
      field: 'stargazers_count',
      title: 'Stars',
      editable: {
        type: 'text'
      },
      formatter: errorFormatter, /* cfa */
    }, {
      field: 'forks_count',
      title: 'Forks',
      editable: {
        type: 'text'
      },
      formatter: errorFormatter, /* cfa */
    }, {
      field: 'errors',
      title: 'Errors',
    }],
    data: data
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="table">

</table>
<hr>
<div>
  If the field name in bootstrapTable is equal to one of the items passed in the error array for that row, then highlight the appropriate cell in that row RED and display message "Error: (print value for that cell) is invalid". When a user clicks on the
  item to edit it, they should still see the original text with a validation error asking them to change it.
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/extensions/editable/bootstrap-table-editable.js"></script>
```